# how to make temporary data frame with a specific data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have data frame with like 1000 rows contain multiple city names and other columns.

I wanted to make another data frame that contains only 10 of most repeated cities and its other columns. i did this:

`df_temp =  df_city[df_city['city_name']].sort_values('city_name')['city_name'].head(10)`

but it didn't work. can anyone tell me how ?

Comment: Do you want to get most repeated **unique** cities or you want to just sort and get first 10?

Comment: I wanted to get most repeated unique cities

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```py
most_freq_cities = df_city['city_name'].sort_values(ascending=False).values[:10]

df_temp = df_city.loc[df_city['city_name'].isin(most_freq_cities)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most repeated unique cities with:

```
most_repeated_unique_cities = df_city['city_name'].value_counts()[:10].index.tolist()
```

And you can get a dataframe containing most repeated unique cities with:

```
df_city[df_city["city_name"].isin(most_repeated_unique_cities)]
```